# Requisito del servidor por error de WordPress «Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ... bytes)»

Tags: php, wordpress

Me aparece este error en wordpress al importar una demo de un tema.

> ```
>  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>  8192 bytes)
> ```

¿Esto es por el servidor? Ya aumenté a `config.php` la memoria limite a 512mb.
Si es así, ¿qué memoria debería contratar? Me ofrecen un plan muy alto y me resulta extraño.

Gracias!.

Comment: Pregunta a tu hosting si permite hacerlo tú directamente...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error *`Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)`* es porque hay algún proceso de Wordpress que requería más memoria de la que tienes asignada para Wordpress.

El mensaje dice que *te quedas corta por unos 8192 bytes* y que intentes asignar más memoria.

Quiero decir algunas cosas al respecto.

1. Puedes cambiar la memoria asignada en `php.ini`, como ya se ha indicado. Ahora bien, si estás en Wordpress, configura Wordpress. Si cambias los valores de `php.ini` porque tienes un problema de Wordpress debes saber que esa configuración afectará a todo el entorno PHP.

   Para dar más memoria al entorno Wordpress puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

   a. Abres el archivo `wp-config.php` que se encontrará en el directorio raíz, llamado generalmente `public_html`.

   b. Buscas si hay una constante parecida a esta: `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );` si la hay, cambias el valor de `512M` por un valor superior. Se entiende que `512M` significa quinientos doce megabytes.

   c. Mucho ojo con ese archivo, no inventes con él, no cometas errores. Con que omitas el `;` tu sitio dejará de funcionar.

-

2. Con lo indicado arriba se configura a nivel de Wordpress. Dando más memoria no deberías tener ese problema. Peeeero, no te conformes con eso. Te mostraré mi configuración actual de Wordpres: `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );` ... Tengo asignado a WP solamente `96M` y no he tenido en años problemas de memoria.

   Recuerdo que al principio tenía mucho ese problema. Con el tiempo aprendí a hacer mis propias funciones yo mismo (porque antes, como no tenía casi idea de PHP, para cualquier cosa tiraba de un plugin... así el sitio se va llenando de plugin: plugin para a, plugin para b, plugin para c, plugin, plugin, plugin, plugin ...). Al final me dije que esto era imposible, que había que hacer algo y me metí en serio a aprender PHP.

   Lo que digo de los plugin vale también para los temas. Hay temas y temas y unos son bastante malos y pesados. Si tienes que elegir un tema, o comprar un tema o estás abonada (o piensas abonarte) a un sitio desde el cual puedes descargar temas, ten cuidado porque es una elección delicada. Si eliges un tema pesado eso se notará. Hay temas muy bonitos y ligeros porque están bien programados. No es una elección banal.

   ¿Resultado? Tengo actualmente un sitio con tráfico considerable, 96M asignados, 2 plugins instalados nada más (uno de ellos de seguridad y de mejora de la memoria caché y demás) y un tema basado en el framework `Thesis`.

   Nunca más volví a ver el mensaje de tu pregunta, el cual en los inicios era muy frecuente.

---

#### Conclusión

No te conformes con aumentar memoria de forma indiscriminada. Verifica por qué te está pidiendo tanta memoria y trata de optimizar lo más que puedas. Este tipo de situaciones tienen su lado positivo: puedes aprovechar para hacer limpieza en tu sitio, por ejemplo borrando plugin que no necesitas.

Otra cosa, muchos plugin dejan basura en tu sitio (en las carpetas, en la base de datos, etc). Son plugin mal programados, que cuando los desinstalas no limpian lo que han creado. (El otro día encontré un rastro de uno de los primeros plugin que había instalado en WP, en el año 2013, estaba en la base de datos y no me había dado cuenta. Era un plugin tan pésimo que había dejado rastros en un lugar recóndito de la base de datos). Hay que hacer limpieza y revisar de vez en cuando.

---

#### Documentación de Wordpress

> Dejo aquí [lo que explica Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) sobre esta opción:
>
> **Aumento de memoria asignada a PHP**
>
> También lanzada con la versión 2.5, la opción `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` le
>   permite especificar la cantidad máxima de memoria que puede consumir
>   PHP. Esta configuración puede ser necesaria en el caso de que reciba
>   un mensaje como "Tamaño de memoria permitido de xxxxxx bytes
>   agotados".
>
> Esta configuración aumenta la memoria PHP solo para WordPress, no para
>   otras aplicaciones. De forma predeterminada, WordPress intentará
>   aumentar la memoria asignada a PHP a 40 MB (el código se encuentra al
>   principio de `/wp-includes/default-constants.php`) para un sitio único
>   y 64 MB para varios sitios, por lo que la configuración en
>   `wp-config.php` debería reflejar algo superior a 40MB o 64MB
>   dependiendo de tu configuración.
>
> WordPress comprobará automáticamente si a PHP se le ha asignado menos
>   memoria que el valor ingresado antes de utilizar esta función. Por
>   ejemplo, si a PHP se le han asignado 64 MB, no es necesario establecer
>   este valor en 64M, ya que WordPress utilizará automáticamente todos
>   los 64 MB si es necesario.
>
> Tenga en cuenta que es posible que esta configuración no funcione si
>   su host no permite aumentar el límite de memoria de PHP; en ese caso,
>   comuníquese con su host para aumentar el límite de memoria de PHP.
>   Además, tenga en cuenta que muchos hosts establecen el límite de PHP
>   en 8MB.
>
> Incrementa la memoria de PHP a 64MB
>
> ```
> define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
> ```
>
> Incrementa la memoria PHP a 96MB
>
> ```
> define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
> ```
>
> Las tareas de administración requieren mucha más memoria de la
>   habitual. Cuando se encuentra en el área de administración, la memoria
>   se puede aumentar o disminuir desde `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` definiendo
>   `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT`.
>
> ```
> define ('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, @A. Cedano, en mi caso el problema estaba en el php.ini ya que no esta escribiendo correctamente el valor y me ha solucionado mi problema. Saludos.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @FernandoTorres. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno el error que te indica es que necesita 536870912 bytes que son a mb = 536.87
[bytes a mb](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=bytes%20to%20mbytes) y configuraste la memoria límite a 512 mb, te faltan algunos mb para completar. Si solo tienes 512 mb de memoria en ese servidor tendrás que contratar más, sino modifica el archivo config.php para que ocupe un poco más de memoria. Con 1gb de memoria podrías estar bien si es un wordpress con poco tráfico.